# How do I get the sum and average of a sequence of random numbers in a list, repeated through a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in range(5):
for j in range(3):
    list1.append(random.randrange(1,101))
list2.append(list1)
list1=[]

for i in range(5):
for j in range(3):
    print(list2[i][j],end=",")
print()
```

There are 5 lines, with 3 random numbers in each line. I want to find the sum of the 3 numbers on each line, and the average of each line. However I have no clue how I should go about doing this.

Comment: Please correct the indentations.

Comment: I believe you're very new to python. In that case here's excellent starting material for you https://automatetheboringstuff.com/. Give it a week and I believe you'll find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be:

```
import random
list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in range(5):
  for j in range(3):
    list1.append(random.randrange(1,101))
    list2.append(list1)
  list1=[]

data=[(data[0], data[0]/float(data[1])) for data in [(reduce((lambda d, i=0: d+i), data),len(data)) for data in list2]]
```

## data[0] is sum and data[1] is average.

```
print("Result: {0}".format(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your indentation. Try below:

```
import random
list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in range(5):
  for j in range(3):
    list1.append(random.randrange(1,101))
  list2.append(list1)
  list1=[]

print("List of random nos, sum , average ")
for i in list2:
    print(i, sum(i), sum(i)/len(i))
```

Once you have the `list2` with random numbers, you may work with the list items as above. sum() gets you the sum, avg = sum(items) / total_no_of_items, total_number_of_items can be found using len() function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
for _list in list2: #Use _list to avoid name clashes with the built-in function
    for item in _list:
        print(item, end=",") #Print each item in the list

    print(" (Sum: ", sum(_list), " Average: ", (sum(_list)/len(_list)), ")", sep="") 

    #Use sum() and len() to find the average

    print() #End with a new line
```

**Example Output**

```
96,56,35, (Sum: 187 Average: 62.333333333333336)

19,88,83, (Sum: 190 Average: 63.333333333333336)

36,71,41, (Sum: 148 Average: 49.333333333333336)

15,88,13, (Sum: 116 Average: 38.666666666666664)

9,18,62, (Sum: 89 Average: 29.666666666666668)
```

*`sum()` returns the sum of all the items in an iterable object and `len()` returns the length of an iterable object. Dividing the sum of the list by the length of the list gives the average of the list.*